# How to configure build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to add cppFlags, but always report error:

`"Error:(16, 0) Could not find property 'cppFlags' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions_Decorated@44658d55.
<a href="openFile:/Users/liut1/Documents/Projects/Android/GitSourceCode/VideoWall/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>"`

Please help me, thanks!

Here are my gradles:

1. top gradle

   ```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

   buildscript {
       repositories {
       jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
           //        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'

           // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
           // in the individual module build.gradle files
       }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
            jcenter()
       }
   }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
         delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
   ```
2. app gradle

   ```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "andrewl.videowall"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       ndk {
            moduleName = "HelloARVideoNative"
   //               cppFlags.add("-I${file("include")}".toString())
           cppFlags.add("-DANDROID")
           cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
           cppFlags.add("-frtti")
           stl = "gnustl_static"
           ldLibs "log","GLESv2"
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   sourceSets {
       main {
           java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java-gen']
           jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
   }
   productFlavors {
       create("arm") {
           ndk.with {
                   abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
               }
           }
       }
   }

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
       compile files('libs/greendao-1.3.7.jar')
   }
   ```
3. gradle wrapper

   ```
   #Mon Dec 28 10:00:20 PST 2015
   distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   distributionPath=wrapper/dists
   zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have look at this. this example contains configuration what you need in your cpp supported application.

```
ndk {
    moduleName = 'hello-jni'
    toolchain = 'clang'
    CFlags.addAll(['-Wall'])
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-jni/app/build.gradle)